# Disappearing Field Boundaries in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon-creation, display

I am creating some polygon features that map farm field boundaries. After creating about 3-4 of them, I noticed that the first one I created disappears from the Map View. If I look at the attributes table, it is still there, and its label shows up. I can even select it and the highlighted outline displays. All the other features in the same layer display. I am at a loss.

Any ideas as to why the feature will not display?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of layer symbology do you have applied?

Comment: If your data is Esri Shapefile, try updating or removing the spatial index.

Comment: How about go to the properties on that layer and go to the Symbology and click on the Categories. What do yo see ?

Comment: I have removed any spatial index from the layer. Only the data layer is projected. It is in fact a shapefile. My layer symbology should be the same for every feature. I tried changing it to Categories by Id (all of the Id's = 0). I do notice that the only feature that is effected is the first feature in the attribute table. All the others are fine.

Comment: I also notice that the feature disappears whenever I Calculate the Geometry (acreage). Before that, it appears to be present.

Comment: Have you populate their names ?  Like add a new field and then name the field and name them each ?

Comment: Yes. As you can see in my image above, the features are actually labelled and the one that "disappeared" still has the label visible.

Comment: Try manual: remove *.sbn and *.sbx files using Windows explorer.

Comment: You have a definition query set on that layer?

Comment: No, I do not have a query definition set on the layer.

Comment: If you Copy Features that layer to a new shapefile, and then add that new shapefile to a new map, is the polygon present in the display?  If not, is it present in the attribute table?

Comment: It was present in the attribute table, but not the display. Even the label was visible. Just the border outline was not. Weird, right?!

Answer (score 1):

I see three potential fixes:

1. Delete the polygon, save and close you edit session, then create a new polygon.
2. Export the data to a new shapefile of geodatabase and then work from this new version.
3. Fix the vector geometry using the 'repair geometry tool' in the Editor toolbox.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model works. Your answer should be clear enough that provide the solution to the specific question. Answers that include expectations, assumes and questions may be removed or downvoted. Instead, you can comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to comment but I need 50 reputation to do so. I will rephrase my answer.